# How does an airline system prevent two users from booking the same seat at the same time?

Tags: java, database, synchronization

If two users try to book the same seat at the same time, only one will succeed. How is this achieved? I read of locking but please throw more light on how this can be achieved. Locks in the code(synchronized keyword) or locks on the database rows or constraints the DB or something else?

Comment: You should read about `database transactions`. Using locks in the code (like synchronized)  only works in the same jvm, which is not helpfull in a larger scalable system.

Comment: @second - This article mentions locking in the code - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/design-movie-ticket-booking-system-like-bookmyshow/

Answer (score -1):

First of all, it is near impossible for two people to book at the same time. Even when they would click on the booking button at the exact same time they would arrive at the server at different time points (due to, connection, distance, ...).

So this event is extremely unlikely. One solution would be to add a "reservation" as soon as somebody clicks on a seat and starts the booking process. This prevents other users from booking the same seat while somebody is currently booking it. If the person doesn't book the seat you can just "unlock" it again.

**Eventbrite**, for example, uses a similar system. They reserve you a ticket as soon as you hit the `get ticket` button. This makes sure that nobody grabs your ticket when you fill out your details.

Comment: "it is near impossible for two people to book at the same time" - I used to think that it is very likely as there will be lot of users and small number of seats. 
"Even when they would click on the booking button at the exact same time .." - "Same time" means the system will calculate the time upto the milliseconds. Won't it?

Comment: I had the assumption that the TO wants a more technical answer. Even if an event is `extremly unlikely` the system has to handle it as it will occur eventually. Still the answer lacks technical details on how that is achieved.

Comment: It is also different depends on how your Backend works. When computers resolve one request after another ther can't be 2 bookings being resolved at the exact same time.

Comment: @second- You are right. I heard of terms such as locking but was looking for answer that goes to greater depths.

Comment: @Ironlors: I doubt a `airline` has such a system in place as it would introduce a `single point of failure`. But you are correct about the backend depencies.

Comment: Sry but I can't deliver more technical details as I am not working much with databases. Could only give theoretical ideas. But there will be definitely somebody else here who knows the answer. Good luck with your question :)